# Как выйти из цикла по другому?

Tags: java

Есть некий цикл (пример)

```
while (!stop)
 {
  if (i = 1)
  {
     // код
    if (stop)
    {
      break;
    }
    // код
    if (stop)
    {
      break;
    }
  }          
}
```

Приходиться писать постоянно if (stop) ..По другому как то можно сделать, чтобы выйти из цикла ?

Comment: ну пишите `continue` постоянно. Это не выход из цикла, а переход к следующей итерации, которая прекратит цикл сразу же при Ваших условиях

Comment: Где в коде устанавливаете флаг ``stop`` сразу пишите ``break``

Comment: Флаг stop устанавливается вне этого цикла (

Comment: Что за код там где написано //код? В первом комментарии. Он связан с переменной stop?

Comment: В цикле нет не связан.

Comment: @Shamon зачем вам тогда  вторая проверка на на stop, ведь она никогда не выполнится.

Comment: @AntonSorokin код между двумя стопами может менять stop

Comment: Приведите более осмысленный пример.

Comment: **"Флаг stop устанавливается вне этого цикла"** --  ну тогда тело цикла вообще никогда не выполнится. Вообще, скорее всего, вам стоит тщательней продумать алгоритм. Такая структура, которую вы хотите соорудить, выглядит неэлегантно.